# Keep double quotes when getting element from JSONArray

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jsonpath

I am using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to retrieve a value from a JSON file. The JSON file looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "username": "John",
    "password": {
      "passwordValue": "passwordjohn",
      "secret_key": "123"
    }
  },
  {
    "username": "Nick",
    "password": {
      "passwordValue": "XXX",
      "secret_key": "ZZZ",
      "other_key": "YYY"
    }
  }
]
```

The JsonPath I am using is to retrieve the `password` from a particular user. Example:

```
fun getPassword() {
    val passwords: JSONArray = read(jsonFile, "\$.[?(@.name==\"John\")].password")
}
```

However, I found two obstacles. Firstly, I get back a `net.minidev.json.JSONArray` always, and the same path with appended `[0]` doesn't work.

Therefore, I try to get the only element from the `JSONArray` I get back, like this: `credentials[0]`. Unfortunately, this **removes** the double quotes in the field names, resulting in something like this:

```
{passwordValue: passwordjohn, secret_key: 123}
```

Which is impossible to work with.

I am looking for a way to get this back:

```
{"passwordValue": "passwordjohn", "secret_key": "123"}
```

Comment: Funnily enough, most past questions ask how to remove the quotes :)

Comment: Check this github issue: 
https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/275#issue-184313633

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to remove the `[` and `]` symbols from the beginning of the `JSONArray` after converting it to a `String`:

```
private fun JSONArray.toCredentialString(): String {
    val credentialString = this.toString()
    return credentialString.substring(1, credentialString.length - 1)
}
```

Any better solution is welcome.